# match condition of second table if value exist sql

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to achieve a simple thing but for me it is getting complicated I hope you guys will help me out I am using left join query and want to make a condition to get single row matching the condition 1 condition to match on 1st table and on second table if the record matching the value exists or not doesn't matter but 1st condition of ID should exist here is the sample query which I am trying to write

```
SELECT team_request.*, (SELECT user_meta.meta_value FROM user_meta WHERE user_meta.meta_title = 'user_image') AS userImage FROM team_request INNER JOIN user_meta ON user_meta.user_id = team_request.user_id WHERE team_request.teamID = '27'
```

But by using above query I am getting an error #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row as of usermeta is option condition if that exist or not not important so can you guys help me out please if you did not understood my question please comment me out because i am not been able to think how do I explain my requirement

Answer (score 0):

It is stated in the error that your subquery `(SELECT user_meta.meta_value FROM user_meta WHERE user_meta.meta_title = 'user_image')` **returns more than one row**. When using a subquery, make sure that it returns only **1 row** so the compiler won't be confused on what row to fetch for the subquery.

### ANSWER #1

You can use the **[MySQL LIMIT](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-limit.aspx)** function to limit your subquery into 1 row. You can revise your subquery to this (by adding **LIMIT 1** at the end of the subquery):

```
(SELECT user_meta.meta_value FROM user_meta 
WHERE user_meta.meta_title = 'user_image' LIMIT 1)
```

**What is **[MySQL LIMIT](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-limit.aspx)** ?**

> The LIMIT clause is used in the SELECT statement to constrain the number of rows to return.

### ANSWER #2

Or to make sure you are fetching the right value, add the `user_id` in the `WHERE` clause of your subquery like this:

```
(SELECT user_meta.meta_value FROM user_meta 
WHERE user_meta.meta_title = 'user_image' and user_meta.user_id = team_request.user_id)
```